# What is causing my md5 hash to come out incorrectly?

Tags: bash, encryption, hash, md5, md5sum

```
#!/bin/bash

# Program's Purpose: Compute time elapsed between epoch time and current time
# Produce an MD5 hash from that time
# Get code from that hash

# compute time elapsed in seconds between epoch time and current time
#EPOCH=$(date -u -d '2001-02-03 04:05:06' '+%F %H:%M:%S')
#CURRENT=$(date -u -d '2010-06-13 12:55:34' '+%F %H:%M:%S')
# code: dd15
EPOCH=$(date -u -d '1999-12-31 23:59:59' '+%F %H:%M:%S')
CURRENT=$(date -u -d '2013-05-06 07:43:25' '+%F %H:%M:%S')
# interval is time elapsed minus time elapsed % 60

echo $EPOCH
echo $CURRENT
read YEAR1 M1 DAY1 HOUR1 MIN1 SEC1 <<< "${EPOCH//[:-]/ }" 
read YEAR2 M2 DAY2 HOUR2 MIN2 SEC2 <<< "${CURRENT//[:-]/ }"
echo $YEAR1 $M1 $DAY1 $HOUR1 $MIN1 $SEC1 

# date in seconds from 
sec1=$(date -d "$EPOCH" -u +%s)
sec2=$(date -d "$CURRENT" -u +%s)
echo $sec1
echo $sec2

# get the difference from the two times
difference=$((sec2 - sec1))
difference=$((difference - ((difference % 60))))
echo $difference

# get the hash from the time
hash=$(echo -n $difference | md5sum | tr -d '\n')
hash=$(echo -n $hash | md5sum | tr -d '\n')
echo $hash

# creating two strings, one with all of the letters
# the other with all of the numbers
letter=$(echo $hash | sed 's/[0-9]*//g' | cut -c1-2)
echo $letter
num=$(echo $hash | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g')
echo $num
#num=$(echo $num | cut -c1-2)
#echo $num

# getting the last two numbers in reverse order
num1=$(echo ${num: -1})
num=$(echo "${num::-1}")
echo $num
num2=$(echo ${num: -1})
code="$letter$num1$num2"
echo $code
```

I'm trying to write a program that takes an epoch time and
current time, computes the difference in seconds, and then creates a
code by doing a double md5 hash on the time in seconds. By what times
I have entered in currently, the difference in seconds should be 421,
141, 406, and the 'code' is supposed to be based on 60-second
intervals, so the code I'm trying to generate should come from 421,
141, 380.

The resulting hash should be
`042876ca07cb2d993601fb40a1525736`, but I am getting
`d49904f9e7e62d0ff16e523d89be08eb`. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing
wrong exactly?

I read that bash leaves a newline at the end of
strings, so I ran echo with `-n` option to remove that newline, but I am
still not getting the preferred results.

Comment: Why are you running `md5sum` **twice**? Also, **what** `String` produces your expected output?

Comment: This was part of an assignment, and we were told to md5 (md5 (difference)), so the variable written as 'difference' is echoed into md5, and then I set 'hash' to be md5 of difference.

Comment: Which final number exactly should produce the expected hash?

Comment: 421141380 is the number to plug in to produce the hash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of `md5sum` on many platforms is not *just* the MD5 sum.  For example, on a GNU/Linux system, you get

```
debian$ echo -n 401 | md5sum
816b112c6105b3ebd537828a39af4818  -
```

Notice that the output has two fields: The actual MD5 sum, followed by two spaces, followed by the input file name (where `-` stands for standard input).

(By contrast, on OSX, and I would expect most *BSDs, you get

```
yosemite$ echo -n 401 | md5
816b112c6105b3ebd537828a39af4818
```

Here, you'll notice that the name of the MD5 utility is different.)

The fix should be simple.  I have refactored your code to *(a)* prefer the portable `printf` over the less portable `echo -n`; *(b)* remove the completely superfluous final `tr -d '\n'` (newlines are trimmed off the end of the captured variable by the shell already); and *(c)* fold everything into a single pipeline.

```
hash=$(printf '%s' "$difference" | md5sum | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | tr -d '\n' |
    md5sum | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
echo "$hash"
```

For completeness, this code also has proper quoting; it's not strictly necessary here (but it would have been if you really needed to preserve the spacing in the value you originally obtained from `md5sum`, for example) but omitting quotes is a common newbie problem which should be avoided.

(Capturing a variable just so you can `echo` it is also a common newbie antipattern; but your code will want to use the variable `hash` subsequently.)

Repeated code is always a bad smell; maybe provide a function which performs the same job as the *BSD `md5` utility;

```
md5 () { md5sum "$@" | cut -d ' ' -f 1; }
hash=$(printf '%s' "$difference" | md5 | tr -d '\n' | md5)
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! Thank you for all of your explanations and suggestions. You really helped me tremendously.